# Working on old commit makes detached HEAD

Tags: git, github

I was working in my project and I had this commits:

Commit 3

Commit 2

Commit 1

For several reasons I went to Commit 2 but I haven't delete Commit 3, so I have started working on Commit 2. Once I have finished I would like to commit and this was the HEAD branch and it gives me a error like there is other commits further or something like that and all the work done have disappear.

Now if I am trying to move to commits and I am receiving this error:

*Doing so will make your working copy a 'detached HEAD', which means you won't be on a branch anymore. If you want to commit after this you'll probably want to either checkout a branch again, or create a new branch. Is this ok?*

So I guess my work is somewhere but I can not figure out where it is or how to restore it.

I didn't know what to write exactly on the title so feel free to edit it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Before you leave a detached HEAD, use `git tag xxx HEAD` or `git branch xxx HEAD` to create a ref for this HEAD so that you can use it or go back to it later. If you forget to do so, use `git reflog` to find the "lost" detached HEADs. They are not deleted.

Comment: numbers HEAD@{8}: commit: Commit text.
I have found there! Do you know how I can put this back? @elpiekay

Comment: What would like to do with it exactly, by "put this back"? You can run `git checkout HEAD@{8}` to check it out, or `git branch xxx HEAD@{8}` to create a branch from it, or `git merge HEAD@{8}` to merge it and its ancestors to the current branch. But better to use the sha1 before it because HEAD@{8} doesn't always point to that commit it is pointing at now.

Comment: Thank you so much it works! If you wanna put it as answer and I can mark it as solution. git reflog helped me to find the "lost" head.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
git commit -am "Commit 4"         # Commit your changes
git branch -m master master_old   # Rename master
git branch -m master              # Make current branch master
```